# How to cast a generic object of type A<T> to A<T'>?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, casting

I have a object of type `MyClass<object>` and I need to convert it to `MyClass<int>` as I know it is containing ints.

If I simply try to do the cast is does not compile:

```
MyClass<object> a = new MyClass<object>();
MyClass<int> b = (MyClass<int>) a;
```

What's wrong and how to do it?

Comment: You can't, because neither is a superclass of the other.

Comment: IMHO this is not how generics are meant to be used. Could you post more code to see why you need this cast

Comment: Even if two types, `T1` and `T2` have an inheritance relationship, that doesn't (generally, ignoring some co/contravariance issues) mean that the generic types `G<T1>` and `G<T2>` have the *same* inheritance relationship.

Comment: The only option here is a conversion, casting isn't applicable.

Comment: Agree: this is not possible. If you try var b = a as MyClass<int> you get a more descriptive error: "Cannot convert type 'MyClass<object>' to 'MyClass{int>' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion"

Comment: @Mehrdad: please can you post your evident answer so I can accept it? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, because neither is a superclass of the other.

Answer (score 4):

You can go with `implicit` cast operator

```
class MyClass<T>
    {
        public static implicit operator MyClass<T>(MyClass<object> input)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

and then the cast is valid

```
MyClass<object> a = new MyClass<object>();
MyClass<int> b = (MyClass<int>) a;

//you don't have to write cast type
MyClass<int> c = a;
```

though you still need to implement exact details of conversion.

EDIT : In case you want to call cast explicitely just change `implicit` keyword to `explicit`

```
class MyClass<T>
    {
        public static explicit operator MyClass<T>(MyClass<object> input)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

which means that you can still use original cast but this becomes invalid

```
   //will not compile now !
   MyClass<object> a = new MyClass<object>();
   MyClass<int> b = a;
```

Comment: an `implicit` cast means you don't have to explicitly cast :). Remove the `MyClass<int>`

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov exactly , the cast code is just for reference to match original question input

Comment: Then create an `explicit` cast, not an `implicit` one.

Comment: I'd not recommend to do `implicit` cast operator. This contradicts with guidelines, since casting from `object` to any `T` may lead to data loss/exceptions.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov i added example of how it looks with explicit cast